# ODBC driver use in Qt

Tags: qt, ms-access, odbc

I wanted to use read and write `mdb` file (Ms Access file) and I am completely new in using `ODBC` in Qt.

So can anyone help me to know whether should i need to download the drivers and if yes then from where can i download ? and if you know about connectivity then any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Talking about odbc here, not java/jdbc. Removing java tags :)

Answer (score 6):

If you need to access an MS Access database with Qt, you don't need (if I'm not mistaken) to install anything regarding drivers (everything should be already there).

You can connect to a database with a connection string. Something like this :

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setDatabaseName("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ=C:\\path\\to\\mydatabase.mdb");
bool Success = db.open();
```

Comment: However, you will need the ODBC drivers to do this. They may need to be built.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problem.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC","AccessDB");
db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};FIL={MS Access};DBQ=C:/path/to/Database.mdb");
bool success = db.open();
```

works for me.