# Detect that the Microsoft Access driver are installed

Tags: c++, qt, ms-access, odbc

I can connect to an old `Access` database with the following code:

```
bool LoadDb(const QString& file_path, QSqlDatabase& db_out, QSqlError& err)
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");

    static const auto DRIVER_NAME = R"({Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)})";
    const auto connection_string = QString(R"(Driver=%1;DSN='';DBQ=%2)").arg(DRIVER_NAME, file_path);
    db.setDatabaseName(connection_string);
    if (!db.open())
    {
        err = db.lastError();
        return false;
    }

    db_out = std::move(db);

    return true;
}
```

But I would like to previously test that the driver ("Microsoft Access Database Engine") is installed so could I show a meaningful message for the user.

The following connection string does not work:

```
const auto connection_string = QString(R"(Driver=%1)").arg(DRIVER_NAME);
```

The error means nothing ... and it is in French:

```
[Microsoft][Pilote ODBC Microsoft Access]Erreur générale Impossible d'ouvrir la clé de Registre « Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0xa74 Thread 0xce4 DBC 0xb5518368                                                              Jet ». QODBC3: Unable to connect
```

Any idea? Preferably portable code.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051147/odbc-driver-use-in-qt

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the `SQLSTATE` you check for an SQLState of `IM002`. I think `IM002` is always returned if the driver cannot be found / loaded, while if for example the database file cannot be found because the path is wrong, you would get a `HY000` `SQLSTATE`:

For an invalid driver string I get:

`SQLSTATE IM002; Native Error: 0; [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

For an invalid path I get:

`SQLSTATE HY000; Native Error: -1044; [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid file name.`

See here for more details about the values returned: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlconnect-function

Comment: Don't have the time to test QT for the moment and I'd prefer not to descend to Windows level. Hopefully, I will come back after some research.

Comment: @Liviu: SQLSTATE is part of the odbc specifications, I would be surprised if you couldn't access its value from the `QSqlError` object.. but I dont know about qt.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlerror.html#nativeErrorCode This should take 5 minutes, but I just quit that job :D. I will install QT try it for a couple of hours, but not now. I will not forget your answer, thanks!